# How do you fill one array with another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Well basically I have this array with images:

```
var random_images = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png","8.png","9.png","10.png","11.png","12.png","13.png","14.png","15.png","16.png","17.png","18.png","19.png","20.png","21.png" ];
```

I want to fill them all [randomly] to another array:

```
 var myArray = new Array(100)  (as you can see i want to fill those images to 100 spaces and each time i refresh the page i need to scatter them randomly)
```

I have tried to do it with:

```
var combinedArray = myArray.concat(random_images);
```

It doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to it?

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/1169519).

Comment: Dear Ralf. You see that people are pointing to an already existing question and answer. If you feel the other answer does not help you, edit your question and explain why. Cheers

Comment: Refer this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/1533666 I'm with @Framester

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = new Array(100);

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    newArray[i] = random_images[Math.floor(Math.random() * random_images.length)];
```

You can try a code like this.